# Sudden jump in the number of unanswered questions by 2000 in a day

Tags: bug, unanswered-questions

On July 21, there were 92572 unanswered questions on Math.SE according to the `unanswered questions` statistic (and not the `not answered` statistic). On July 22, there were 94797 unanswered questions — a difference of over 2000. This is visible in the Unanswered Question Tracker in the [Crusader's Chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141/the-crusade-of-answers).

We didn't get 2000 more questions in a day. I see perhaps five possibilities:

1. Stack Exchange changed its fundamental definition of an unanswered question in some way, perhaps just on some sites (like perhaps Trinity+Math, or SO+Math, or some other age/volume based way). Under the new definition, approximately 2000 more questions became unanswered.
2. A 2000+ vote user deleted their account for some reason.
3. A very large amount of voting fraud was caught and automatically reversed by either the Celestial Thaumaturges (CommTeam) above or the automatic script.
4. As unlikely as it is, a very large number of users just happened to downvote/remove upvotes/unaccept answers in the same day.

Alternately, either the API from which the Unanswered Question Tracker from lied (though rather consistently for a very long time) and/or the Unanswered Question Tracker is simply buggy (although it is correct now, and no change has been made to it).

This is mysterious to me, and I do not understand what has happened.

Comment: Is the source code of your tracker available? Just curious to know where the data comes from.

Comment: There was a user removed at `2015-07-23 18:03:51Z`: most of very active answerers lost 10-30 points at that time. But that was only 12 hours ago, and the jump you observed predates that by a day.

Comment: I know it's a math website, so it's not reasonable to expect someone to count all the way up to five... but you only listed *four* possibilities. Is this your proof that $\sf PA$ is inconsistent? :-)

Comment: He said "perhaps five."  (The fifth possibility is not numbered, indicating the uncertainty of its inclusion in the list.)

Comment: If you want to know about (1) you can ask it on Meta.SE, or alternatively, I suspect moderators have a direct way of communicating with SE? For (2), can't moderators can see the history of deleted users?

Comment: @wythagoras in fact, I was talking directly with two members of the Comm Team. They were stumped, and one eventually asked me to put it on meta.

Comment: @mixedmath Okay. Also, what is exactly the purpose of the room? Is there something I may contribute to?

Comment: I'm going to reprint our team's business cards to denote that we are Celestial Thaumaturges.

Comment: Maybe this should be tagged (status-completed), if you are statistified by Normal Human's answer.

Answer (score 17):

The [Unanswered tab](https://math.stackexchange.com/unanswered) used to suffer  from a couple of bugs or inconsistencies. Both concerned the content with negative score.

1. A bug reported on Meta recently, [Unanswered section does not include questions with negatively scored answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251096/unanswered-section-does-not-include-questions-with-negatively-scored-answers). Illogically, the tab did not include the questions where there was at least one answer but all answers had **negative** score. There are [755 such questions](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/339610/questions-where-all-answers-have-negative-score) on Math. Now they are visible on the Unanswered tab.
2. An inconsistency between Unanswered tab and Questions/unanswered subtab. The former [excluded questions with negative score](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/244344/), the latter did not. As of now, negatively scored unanswered questions [do appear on the Unanswered tab](https://math.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?page=1900&tab=votes). There are [1238 such questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?page=25&tab=votes&q=isanswered%3a0%20hasaccepted%3a0%20closed%3a0%20score%3a..-1) on Math.

Taken together, the above should explain the jump of about 2000 questions. I presume that the cleanup of the queries underlying these views had to do with the [ongoing reform of SE site navigation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261307/improving-our-navigation-the-next-iteration), which in particular will fold the Unanswered tab into a particular view of the main page.